# How high does a user's reputation have to be for their votes not to be removed if their account is deleted?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) explains the process but doesn't mention the threshold. If there is an explicit threshold and it is not mentioned, why is that the case? Would mentioning the threshold somehow alter the dynamic / people's incentives in an undesirable way? Or is there no threshold and decisions are made on a case-by-case basis? (However, even if the latter were the case, I guess there must still be a threshold that triggers the manual review?)

I have nothing against the feature and am just interested from a theoretical / community-building perspective.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know, the exact thresholds are intentionally not documented anywhere. Probably more because it's complicated than to prevent attempts to game the system, but both are valid concerns.

The best you get is [this answer from Shog9 discussing the implementation of the feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/153008), which says, in part (emphasis added):

> Here's how it works:
>
> - There are two thresholds:
>
>   1. Number of votes cast by the user being deleted
>   2. Number of people affected significantly by those votes
>
>   The exact values of those thresholds don't particularly matter;
>     they're pretty low, but not so low that you could hit them easily
>     while still hiding fraudulent activity.
> - If *either* threshold is exceeded, deletion is held up until someone reviews it. Otherwise, deletion proceeds and any votes are discarded.
> - If, during review, it becomes apparent that the user is *or ever was* involved in voting fraud, the votes are discarded as they would
>     normally be.
> - Otherwise, the votes are preserved.
>
> The end result of this is that **most users will still see votes being
>   removed along with user deletions from time to time... But rarely if
>   ever will these votes cause a non-trivial drop in reputation or a
>   sudden, wide-spread skew in post scores, which were the primary
>   complaints in the past.**

Prior to the implementation of this feature, staff members used to have to [manually perform a special deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156520/153008) that [did not invalidate the votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173045/wiping-votes-on-deletion-of-highly-active-accounts-865-points-on-user-was-rem/173699#173699) cast by that user.

Comment: So in answer to the title question the user's reputation is completely irrelevant then?

Comment: It sounds like that's the case to me.

Comment: Yes, that's my reading of Shog9's answer, @Martin. I'm not sure why the help page is written the way it is. It is either old text that wasn't updated when this system was revamped, or (more likely), they are using "high reputation" as a synonym for "significant number of votes cast" because it's easier to understand and generally quite true (as the next sentence goes on to explain).